# Find: $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculate the following limit:

> $$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+1}\right)$$

I need find this limit without l'Hospital or Taylor series.

Wolfram alpha gives $\frac{1}{2}$

My try is:

Let: $a=\sqrt{1+x^{2}}$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{1+x^{3}}$

And we know that:

$a-b=\frac{a^{3}-b^{3}}{a^{2}+b^{2}+ab}$

But after applied this I find again the problems $0.+\infty$ indeterminate

Comment: You probably need $a-b = (a^6-b^6)/(a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5)$.

Comment: Can you use $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+x)^a-1}x = a?$$

Answer (score 1):

$x(x(1+\frac 1 {x^{2}})^{1/2}- x(1+\frac 1 {x^{3}})^{1/3})=x^{2}(1+\frac 1 {2x^{2}}-1-\frac 1 {3x^{3}}+o(\frac 1 {x^{2}}) \to 1/2$ as $x \to \infty$

Answer (score 1):

Note 
$$\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-x=x \left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}-1\right)=\frac{\frac1x}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}+1}$$

$$\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+1}-x=x \left(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^3}}-1\right)=\frac{\frac1{x^2}}{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^2}}+1}$$

Thus,

$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+1}\right)
=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty}x\left[\left(\sqrt{x^{2}+1}-x\right) -\left(\sqrt[3]{x^{3}+1}-x \right)\right]$$
$$ =\displaystyle\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}+1}
-\frac{\frac1x}{\sqrt[3]{\left(1+\frac1{x^2}\right)^2}+\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^2}}+1}$$
$$=\frac12-0=\frac12$$

Answer (score 1):

If you know the limit $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}=a,$$
then you can do the following.

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L &=&\lim_{x\to +\infty} x\left(x\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}-x\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^3}}\right)=\\
&=&\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^2\left(\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}-1+1-\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^3}}\right)=\\
&=&\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left[\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}-1}{\frac1{x^2}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{1+\frac1{x^3}}-1}{\frac1{x^3}}\frac1{x}\right]=\\
&=&\frac12 -0=\\
&=&\frac12.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: +1 for using standard limits.